# xsl: replace nodes name with regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

there is a method to replace the name of all nodes that start with a particular string?

Example:

```
<ABCDocument ... >
    <ABCElement ... />
    ....
    <ABCElement ... />
</ABCDocument>
```

Desired output:

```
<XYZDocument ... >
    <XYZElement ... />
    ....
    <XYZElement ... />
</XYZDocument>
```

In short what I need is to replace, in all node names, the prefix ABC with the prefix XYZ.
There is a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `replace` function you need an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML, but for your simple case you can write e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'ABC')]">
  <xsl:element name="XYZ{substring(local-name(), 4)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, for the whole approach to work, also use the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in your stylesheet, to copy the other nodes unchanged and to keep up the processing.

Comment: Oh that's great, really useful.

Comment: @azzardo: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.